# Using magellan geospatial library with apache spark for standalone applications

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, geospatial

I am trying to run simple test code in `pyspark` for printing points using magellan library like from the github repository, but I have problem of undefined `sc` context.

If I run it from command line with proposed command `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages harsha2010:magellan:1.0.2-s_2.10` everything works because `sc` is imported automatically but if I run it as a standalone application from `eclipse` it does not recognize `sc`.

I have tried all combinations for its initialization including this piece of code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from magellan.types import Point
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext
#from magellan-master.python.magellan.context import sc
sc = SparkContext(appName="MyGeoFencing")
#sql = SQLContext(sc)
#from magellan.context import sc
#from magellan.context import sc
#from magellan.context import SQLContext
PointRecord = Row("id", "point")
#sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("MyGeoFencing")
#sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)
#sql = SQLContext(sc)
sqlCont = SQLContext(sc)


points = sqlCont.parallelize([
  (0, Point(-1.0, -1.0)),
  (1, Point(-1.0, 1.0)),
  (2, Point(1.0, -1.0))]).map(lambda x: PointRecord(*x)).toDF()


points.show()
```

Here is the problem that `sqlCont` does not have method `parallelize`.
I even tried importing directly `sc` from `magellan.context`, but does not work either.

The same problem stands when I use `scala`!

Do you have some idea how this should work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```